# Fire an event when any variable has changed

Tags: c#, events, variables

I have a form which shows information about variables of the programm. So know I want to update the form when any of the variables changed. Is there any way to trigger an event or something like that?

Comment: I sat in front of my PC for a hour thinking of a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such ability, unless you code it yourself or use some super-advanced-code-instrumentation tool.

I suggest that you use *properties* instead of fields (unless you actually mean local variables?) and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Answer (score 0):

well there are many ways but what i use is observable collectionchanged event so wheneever the event is triggered it will do its operation like below...

```
static void ObservableEmployees_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                 case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    Console.WriteLine("New item {0} added in the collection",e.NewItems[0].ToString());
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    Console.WriteLine("Old item {0} removed in the collection", e.OldItems[0].ToString());
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                    Console.WriteLine("item {0} is moved", e.NewItems[0].ToString());
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                    Console.WriteLine("item{0} is replacced by item{1}.", e.OldItems[0].ToString(), e.NewItems[0].ToString());
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    Console.WriteLine("itme{0} is reset.", e.OldItems[0].ToString());
                    break;
```

}

and for subscription..

```
observableEmployees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

            observableEmployees.CollectionChanged += ObservableEmployees_CollectionChanged;
```